# Asterisk - Quit call after 10 minutes if there's no input

Tags: asterisk

I have an Asterisk server running where a lot of people will call on in the future.

Is it possible to configure the server that if the caller doesn't press a number (or * and #) on his phone for like 10 minutes it automatically hangs up?

Thanks for your help and best regards

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any builtin functionality which would adresses your usecase.

There is the parameter L() of the Dial application which allows to limit the call duration and plays announcements before the limit is reached.
But that does not fit your usecase.

I expect you have to write a custom application which listens on the manager interface and track incoming calls and Events to hangup the channels by yourself...

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
s,n,ResponseTimeout(600)
```

Or:

```
s,n,Set(TIMEOUT(response)=600)
```

Then add an extension to the dial plan to hang up the call:

```
t,1,Hangup()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1) use TIMEOUT(response). This one is exactly for your case, but not work for some dialplan.

2) Use TIMEOUT(absolute) and update it after any new input. This work for any dialplan, but it absolute(i.e will hangup even if you have input).

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+timeout